# How can I scrape a website if the attributes are randomized?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape this website: https://novel5s.com/bye-my-irresistible-love-by-goreous-novel5-online-2138/148981.html.

The problem is that the text is saved in attributes and randomized at every reload. Can someone help me scrap this page by using python?

Double-click on the bottom paragraphs, and you will see that everything is not text.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://novel5s.com/bye-my-irresistible-love-by-goreous-novel5-online-2138/148981.html")
time.sleep(2)
text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".content-book")
for i in text.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"*"):
    attrs=[]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i.get_attribute("outerHTML"),"html.parser")
    try:
        # print(soup.find("p").text)
        print(soup.find("p").attrs.values())
    except:
        pass
print("null")
```

I am trying to get the full paragraph which is inside different attributes of paragraph tag. I know how to get all attributes of a tag but the problem is there are multiple attributes, some of them are just to prevent scraping. I want to get full paragraph.

Edit:
You need to just get ::before and ::after attributes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page, you'll see that the text of the book is actually under the class:

```
class="content-book my-4"
```

So, target that class.

Now you can't just use:

```
 soup.find_all(class_="content-book my-4")
```

since that would give us unnecessary `<script>` tags:

```
<div class="content-book my-4"><p> <strong>Chapter 2 Sick Feeling</strong></p><p> Scarlett’s POV:</p><p> “Anything else?” I asked in disbelief.</p><p> “We have to get up early to see Rita tomorrow,” Charles replied coldly.</p><p> “Okay.”</p><p> I was confused. I could not help but wonder if he returned just to make a point.</p><p> “I’ll sleep here tonight,” he added.</p><p> I came to my senses the instant I heard what he had said. I wanted to ask him if it was really okay for
```

So, instead, use a CSS selector:

```py
for element in soup.select(".content-book.my-4 p"):
    print(element.text)
```

This will select a `<p>` under the class of `content-book my-4`. (This is for Chapter 2, but it still works on chapter 1).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://novel5s.com/bye-my-irresistible-love-by-goreous-novel5-online-2138/148982.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

for element in soup.select(".content-book.my-4 p"):
    print(element.text)
```

Output:

```
 Chapter 2 Sick Feeling
 Scarlett’s POV:
 “Anything else?” I asked in disbelief.
 “We have to get up early to see Rita tomorrow,” Charles replied coldly.
 “Okay.”
 I was confused. I could not help but wonder if he returned just to make a point.
 “I’ll sleep here tonight,” he added.
 I came to my senses the instant I heard what he had said. I wanted to ask him if it was really okay for him to stay here, but I decided to swallow my words instead.
 “I’m afraid you’ll oversleep because of the jet lag,” he 
...
```

Comment: Check all the sentences printed, the few last sentence are not complete. Wait I am editing the code check that.

Answer (score -1):

The order of the hidden text seems to be encoded in the `style` element in the webpage html, just below the `div` element containing all paragraphs (see screenshot).

The codes in this `style` element seem to correspond to the `class` and randomized tags in the paragraph elements that you have trouble with parsing.

My suggestion would be to parse this `style` element, extract the classes and tags in the right order, and parse those from the paragraph elements to get the complete paragraphs.

It would still require some parsing and decoding, but I hope this helps!

Screenshot: [The element that presumably encodes the text order contained in randomized tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecdFX.jpg)